Multidex error reason I have multiple dependencies

Transform classes.jar (project :firebase_storage) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
ERROR:C:\Users\sugas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_storage-11.7.1\android\build\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointe
rException


Transform classes.jar (project :url_launcher_android) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
ERROR:C:\Users\sugas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\url_launcher_android-6.3.0\android\build\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPoi
nterException


Transform classes.jar (project :firebase_core) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
ERROR:C:\Users\sugas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_core-2.29.0\android\build\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerEx
ception


Transform classes.jar (project :cloud_firestore) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
ERROR:C:\Users\sugas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.16.1\android\build\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointer
Exception


Transform classes.jar (project :firebase_auth) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
ERROR:C:\Users\sugas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_auth-4.19.1\android\build\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerEx
ception


Transform classes.jar (project :webview_flutter_android) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
ERROR:C:\Users\sugas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\webview_flutter_android-3.16.0\android\build\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar: D8: java.lang.Nul
lPointerException


Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libVkLayer_khronos_validation.so, libflutter.so.


Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings


Task :app:mergeDexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exceptio
i try to build android apk in flutter but i show this error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
